# How to add a notification drawer to the toolbar in Jira

Tags: jira

We recently switched to Jira+Confluence and I am quite puzzled by the notification drawer.

In Confluence, the toolbar has a notification drawer, where I receive notifications about activity on Jira issues I am participating to:

[image: The notification drawer in Confluence toolbar]

So, if someone comments on one of my issues in Jira, I see a small notification in Confluence and can jump there to see more. So far, so good.

The strange thing is that this notification drawer is that it does not appear in the Jira toolbar itself:

[image: The absence of a notification drawer in Jira toolbar]

It seems rather odd to me that Confluence offers me an easy access to Jira activities I could be interested in while Jira itself does not.

I reviewed the configuration options in my profile and made unsuccessful basic researches on this question.

1. Is there any way to enable this notification drawer in Jira?
2. If not, what is the rationale being this choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Notification Drawer* is only available in Confluence.

It has been requested for JIRA as well, see [JRA-32465](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-32465). Atlassian answered that they would not work on it for now. If you'd like to have it, you should vote on the issue. Atlassian sometimes does pick up requests with lots of votes.

To receive notifications from JIRA directly, some options are to configure [email notifications](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/configuring-email-notifications-802592925.html), or if you use a messaging application like hipchat or slack, you could have JIRA send notifications to chat rooms.

More info about integrating JIRA with Hipchat is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/integrating-with-collaboration-tools-802592230.html).
And for Slack, look [here](https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS3MZ-jira).